# Calculating Modular Arithmetic in the below way

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I calculate:

> $a \pmod c + b \pmod c$

using the modular arithmetic:

> $(a+b) \pmod c = (a \pmod c + b \pmod c)\pmod c$

For example, assuming that $a=14, b=17$ and $c=5$;

$(a+b) \pmod c = (a \pmod c + b \pmod c) \pmod c$

$31   \pmod 5 = (  4     +    2   ) \pmod 5$

I just want $6 (4+2)$ to be the output.

One way to calculate it is to perform $(a \pmod c + b \pmod c).$

But how do I calculate that value without performing in the above mentioned way but by using $(a+b) \pmod c$ ?

Comment: In the line "(a mod c + b mod c) mod c"  the second modulo operator would not change the answer.

Comment: Sorry! But I didn't get you. @Sky  I also placed an example in the question now.

Comment: You have $\;14\bmod5+17\bmod5=4\bmod5+2\bmod5=6\bmod 5=1\bmod5$.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible if we are only allowed to use $(a+b)$ without access to the individual values of $a$ and $b$.

Consider $a=7,b=14,c=5$, so $a+b \mod 5=1$ and $a\mod5+b\mod5=6$.

And also consider $a=10,b=11,c=5$, again $a+b \mod5=1$ but $a\mod5+b\mod5=1$.

In both cases $a+b=21$, and there as there is no means of recovering the initial values of $a$ and $b$, we are stumped.